# How to use IFS= read when you have two input files to perform a sed to replace two values on specific line number?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file names `fileA.txt` with "x" quantity of line numbers. I need to replace a string named `No_IP_Found` with an IPAddr but on specific lines. I have the line numbers I need to replace in a file named `linenum.txt` (lets say line `1` and `4`); and another file name `ipaddr.txt` with the IpAddresses (2 IP Address are listed; lets say `192.168.1.1`, `192.168.1.2`). The files always match linumbers qty with IP Address. So line `1` belongs to `192.168.1.1`, line `4` belongs to `192.168.1.2` and so on.

I know i can use `sed` with specified line I want to replace; example line `1` to be replace with `sed` is:  `sed '1s/No_IP_Address/192.168.1.1/' fileA.txt`   Im using `IFS= read` to perform this operation but I dont know how to makee it worked when I have two input files.

```
$ cat linenum.txt
1
4

$ cat ipaddr.txt
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2

$ cat fileA.txt
SW-01-PR    No_IP_Found     POE_SWITCH
SW-0W-XT    192.168.10.10   HR_SWITCH
SW-2K-RR    192.168.10.11   GYM_SWITCH
SW-3F-PR    No_IP_Found     3F-SWITCH
SW-11-EE    192.168.10.20   EE-SWITCH
```

Desired New Output

```
SW-01-PR    192.168.1.1     POE_SWITCH
SW-0W-XT    192.168.10.10   HR_SWITCH
SW-2K-RR    192.168.10.11   GYM_SWITCH
SW-3F-PR    192.168.1.2     3F-SWITCH
SW-11-EE    192.168.10.20   EE-SWITCH
```

I have the following code; but didnt worked; I have no idea how to make two inputs worked and use sed to replace the lines with the specific string on specific line. Or maybe awk?

```
while IFS= read -r linenum && IFS= read -r ipadd <&3; do
   sed "${linenum}s/No_IP_Found/$ipadd" fileA.txt
done <linenum.txt 3<ipaddr.txt
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You need the `-i` option to `sed` to write the result back to the file.

Comment: It worked.. Thanks. Its there any way to do it without the -i option so it wont overwrite and  create a new file like fileB.txt. ITs not necessarily; I can perform a backup before the overwrite but just asking. I tried this but didnt worked. "sed "${linenum}s/No_IP_Found/$ipadd/" fileA.txt > fileB.txt"

Comment: Each time through the loop you'll start with the same original file, so you won't accumulate all the changes. You could first copy to `fileB.txt` and then update that in place in the loop.

Comment: Thanks.. What does the <&3 do? and the 3<ipaddr.txt.  Without the <&3 in the first line and the 3<ipaddr.txt in the last line failed. Just want to learn the magic of #3. Thanks again!

Comment: `<&3` redirects standard input to file descriptor 3, it's equivalent to using the `-u 3` option with `read`. This works together with `3<ipaddr.txt` which connects file descriptor 3 to the `ipaddr.txt` file.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '
    NR==FNR { a[$1]=$2; next }
    $2 == "No_IP_Found" && a[FNR]{$2 = a[FNR]}1
' <(paste linenum.txt ipaddr.txt) fileA.txt|column -t

SW-01-PR  192.168.1.1    POE_SWITCH
SW-0W-XT  192.168.10.10  HR_SWITCH
SW-2K-RR  192.168.10.11  GYM_SWITCH
SW-3F-PR  192.168.1.2    3F-SWITCH
SW-11-EE  192.168.10.20  EE-SWITCH
```

Formatting rows and using inplace

```
awk -i inplace '
    NR==FNR { a[$1]=$2; next }
    $2 == "No_IP_Found" && a[FNR]{$2 = a[FNR]}
    {
        printf "%s %s %-16s %s\n", $1, FS, $2, $3
    }
' inplace::enable=0 <(paste linenum.txt ipaddr.txt) inplace::enable=1 fileA.txt

$ cat fileA.txt
SW-01-PR   192.168.1.1      POE_SWITCH
SW-0W-XT   192.168.10.10    HR_SWITCH
SW-2K-RR   192.168.10.11    GYM_SWITCH
SW-3F-PR   192.168.1.2      3F-SWITCH
SW-11-EE   192.168.10.20    EE-SWITCH
```

Comment: As the OP apparently want in place editing you could add a note about the GNU awk `inplace` extension: `awk -i inplace '...' inplace::enable=0 <(paste ...) inplace::enable=1 fileA.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

Fixing a syntax issue with the `sed` script (adding a `/` to the end), adding the `-i` option (per Barmar) to update `fileA.txt` with the changes

```
while IFS= read -r linenum && IFS= read -r ipadd <&3; do
   sed -i "${linenum}s/No_IP_Found/$ipadd/" fileA.txt
done <linenum.txt 3<ipaddr.txt
```

Since the two input files only contain single fields (ie, no delimiters to worry about) there's actually no need (in this case) for the `IFS=` clauses so this should also work:

```
while read -r linenum && read -r ipadd <&3; do
   sed -i "${linenum}s/No_IP_Found/$ipadd/" fileA.txt
done <linenum.txt 3<ipaddr.txt
```

Since the two input files have the same number of lines we could also use `paste` to feed a single `read` like such:

```
while read -r linenum ipadd; do
   sed -i "${linenum}s/No_IP_Found/$ipadd/" fileA.txt
done < <(paste linenum.txt ipaddr.txt)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should certainly use `awk` for this, but if you're going to use `sed` one fragile option is to build up the command string and just run `sed` once.  Something like:

```
$ paste linenum.txt ipaddr.txt  | { while read line ip; do
      cmd="$cmd -e ${line}s/No_IP_Found/$ip/"; done;
      sed $cmd fileA.txt ; }
SW-01-PR    192.168.1.1     POE_SWITCH
SW-0W-XT    192.168.10.10   HR_SWITCH
SW-2K-RR    192.168.10.11   GYM_SWITCH
SW-3F-PR    192.168.1.2     3F-SWITCH
SW-11-EE    192.168.10.20   EE-SWITCH
```

Note that `sed -i` is a tragedy and should never be used, and using it in a loop to repeatedly edit the same file is a recipe for disaster.   It is much cleaner to write your output somewhere else. Also note that despite its name, "in-place" editing (almost) never actually edits the file in place. It (almost always) creates a new file and renames it.  This may not be an issue, but people using `-i` options ought to be aware of this fact.

Answer (score 0):

It can also be done with [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/):

```
cat fileA.txt | jq -Rrs --rawfile linenum linenum.txt --rawfile ipaddr ipaddr.txt '
($linenum|split("\n")|map(tonumber?|.-1)) as $rows_to_change
|($ipaddr|split("\n")) as $new_ips
|split("\n")|map(select(.!=""))
|reduce ($rows_to_change|keys)[] as $i ( 
    .; .[$rows_to_change[$i]] |= sub("No_IP_Found";$new_ips[$i]) 
)|.[]'
```